# Gradle generateDebugSources process

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I downloaded Android Studio and installed it to my Ubuntu 14.04 running computer. In Android Studio, generateDebugSources process is always running and never ending even though I tried to stop it, it has been saying "stopping Gradle: Executing Tasks [app:generateDebugSources, ...]" for hours. And when I check the logcat, which has a long list of logs, it lists lines like

```
06-30 13:19:22.441    3053-3363/? D/PowerManagerService﹕ [api] isForceUnblankDisplay : false
06-30 13:19:22.656    3053-3214/? V/AlarmManager﹕ waitForAlarm result :4

06-30 13:19:22.941    3053-3549/? D/PowerManagerService﹕ [api] isForceUnblankDisplay : false

06-30 13:19:23.201    3053-3064/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 5394K, 30% free 74753K/105352K, paused 32ms+25ms, total 513ms

06-30 13:19:23.391    3312-3312/? D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController﹕ onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength: 10 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 -1 2147483647 gsm|lte 0x3 level=3

06-30 13:19:23.391    3312-3312/? D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController﹕ Nothing, mRoamingIconId = 0

...

06-30 13:19:26.341    3053-3206/? I/ServiceKeeper﹕ In getseinfo pid = 3053 uid = 1000 seinfo= system

06-30 13:19:26.406    3053-3206/? I/ServiceKeeper﹕ In getseinfo pid = 3053 uid = 1000 seinfo= system

06-30 13:19:26.451    3053-3509/? D/PowerManagerService﹕ [api] isForceUnblankDisplay : false

06-30 13:19:26.456    3053-3206/? I/ServiceKeeper﹕ In getseinfo pid = 3053 uid = 1000 seinfo= system

06-30 13:19:26.526    3053-3206/? I/ServiceKeeper﹕ In getseinfo pid = 3053 uid = 1000 seinfo= system

06-30 13:19:26.531    3053-3565/? W/ActivityManager﹕ destPackageName = null

06-30 13:19:26.541    3053-3206/? I/ServiceKeeper﹕ In getseinfo pid = 3053 uid = 1000 seinfo= system

...

06-30 13:19:31.676    3053-3578/? D/BatteryService﹕ level:82, scale:100, status:2, health:2, present:true, voltage: 4161, temperature: 312, technology: Li-ion, AC powered:false, USB powered:true, Wireless powered:false, icon:17303411, invalid charger:0, online:4, current avg:460, charge type:1, power sharing:false
06-30 13:19:31.676    3053-3053/? D/BatteryService﹕ Sending ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED.
06-30 13:19:31.691    3312-3312/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor﹕ received broadcast android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
06-30 13:19:31.696    3053-3053/? D/UiModeManager﹕ mCoverManager.getCoverState() : true
06-30 13:19:31.701    3053-3578/? D/BatteryService﹕ stay LED for charging
06-30 13:19:31.711    3312-3312/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor﹕ handleBatteryUpdate
06-30 13:19:31.741    3312-3312/? D/STATUSBAR-PhoneStatusBar﹕ mBrightnessEnablebySettings = true mBrightnessEnablebyBattery = true mBrightnessEnablebyDisableFlag = true mPmsBrightnessEnablebySettings = true
06-30 13:19:31.746    3312-3312/? D/BatteryMeterView﹕ ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED : level:82 status:2 health:2
```

And a lot more lines with similar logs.

Last night I had the same problem. I deleted everything including .gradle in my home folder. This morning I reinstalled Android Studio but still getting the same problem. I searched the problem in Google, added gradle.properties file and inserted necessary lines there but still no help. If you have any idea, I would be appreciative to hear.

Comment: I installed Android Studio on Windows 8.1 and it worked without any problem. I don't know why it has issues on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS but seems to work fine on Windows.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and I'm almost giving up Android Studio ...

Comment: In fact this is a problem Gradle as IntelliJ Idea also for the same task

Comment: Then still there is no solution to this problem?!